# Inequality for a two variables function

Tags: limits, functions

I have tried to solve this exercise but I am having difficulties.

I have to find a function greater than $$\frac{|y|^\alpha \sin(xy)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$ as the parameter $\alpha$ changes.
That's what I tried:

Since $$sin(xy)\leq1$$

$$\frac{|y|^\alpha \sin(xy)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \leq \frac{|y|^\alpha}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$

Then:

$$(x^2+y^2)^{3/2} \geq y^3 $$ so that:

$$\frac{|y|^\alpha}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \leq \frac{|y|^\alpha}{y^{3}}$$
Now I have problems and I don't know what I did wrong. Following my reasoning I should have:
$$\frac{|y|^\alpha}{y^{3}}=|y|^{\alpha - 3}$$
But I Know it's wrong.

Comment: @mfl I'm asking if the steps i have done are correct, so that $\frac{|y|^\alpha sin(xy)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \leq |y|^{\alpha-3}$

Answer (score 1):

$(x^2+y^2)^{3/2} >= y^2 $ is not correct.  Take  $x=0, y=0.1.$

Comment: Typo error sorry, I meant $(x^2+y^2)^{3/2} \geq y^3$

Answer (score 1):

$x^2, y^2 \geq 0$ thus $x^2 + y^2 \geq 0$ and $x^2+y^2\geq y^2$ because $x^2 \geq 0$.

Then put both sides to the power $\frac{3}{2}$

$(x^2+y^2)^\frac{3}{2}\geq (y^2)^\frac{3}{2}=|y|^3$ instead of $y^2$

and we can do this because $y^2 \geq 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 \geq 0$ and $\frac{d}{dz}[z^\frac{3}{2}]=\frac{3}{2}z^\frac{1}{2}\geq 0$ for $z\geq 0$, i.e. $z^\frac{3}{2}$ is an increasing function, so if $z_2\geq z_1$ then $z_2^\frac{3}{2} \geq z_1^\frac{3}{2}$.

Other than that, it doesn't look like the typo really affected your answer.

Comment: Ok thank you, I corrected the typo but my final result doesn't seem correct. I mean $$\frac{|y|^\alpha sin(xy)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \leq |y|^{\alpha-3}$$ or is it correct?
Because in this case, if I make the limit for $y \rightarrow 0$ it goes to zero when $\alpha > 3$
But on the book is for $\alpha > 2$ that's my problem.

Comment: The result is correct because the inequality holds. But it just covers the case $a>3$. Maybe you should ask another question and specify that issue, because your work is good for $a>3$, so specify that you need help for $a>2$.

Comment: ok thank you, I'll do it. Do you mean a new thread or i can just edit this one?

Comment: Try a new one, say what you got for $a>3$ and specify the book says $a>2$ and need help... :)

Comment: Because it’s not clear that $a>2$ was your issue in this problem.

Comment: Ok thank you very much